# scp -i /Downloads/class4.pem/ ec2-user@hostip: /home/ec2-user/test

Tags: linux, scp, aws

```
scp -i /Downloads/class4.pem/ ec2-user@hostip: /home/ec2-user/test
```

i am trying to upload file from local mac to ec 2 ,what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using literally that text?  What errors are you getting?  You might want to check the spaces and extra slash…

Answer (score 1):

- Like almost all(*) unix tools involving copying or moving files, the source file(s) should be specified **before** the destination.   And, unless you use scp's `-r` option to recursively copy an entire directory tree, you also need to specify an actual filename (or glob pattern matching one or more filenames) as the source.
- The destination can be either a single complete filename OR a directory (and when copying multiple files or a recursive directory tree, **should** be a directory).
- `scp` defaults to the user's home directory when given a source or target like `user@host:` (or just `host:` when the local username is the same as the remote username, or the username is provided by a rule in `~/.ssh/config`)
- The identity file (i.e. the private key) is a **file**, not a directory, so `/Downloads/class4.pem` should **not** have a trailing `/`.   Also note that the identity file must not be accessible by others - i.e. it should be owned by the user running `scp` and should be readable only by that user (e.g. permissions 600 or 400).

Your command:

```
scp -i /Downloads/class4.pem ec2-user@hostip: /home/ec2-user/test
```

is attempting to copy **FROM** `ec2-user@hostip:` **TO** `/home/ec2-user/test`.

This will fail with an error message like `scp: .: not a regular file` because `ec2-user@hostip:` does not specify an actual file and you are not using the `-r` option.

If you want to copy local file `/home/ec2-user/test` to ec2-user's home directory on `hostip`, try this:

```
scp -i /Downloads/class4.pem /home/ec2-user/test ec2-user@hostip:
```

If `test` is a directory rather than a file and you want to copy the entire directory to `~ec2-user/test/` in `hostip`, use `-r`:

```
    scp -i /Downloads/class4.pem -r /home/ec2-user/test/ ec2-user@hostip:
```

or to copy just the files in the top level of local directory `/home/ec2-user/test/` into remote user `ec2-user`'s home directory on hostip:

```
    scp -i /Downloads/class4.pem /home/ec2-user/test/* ec2-user@hostip:
```

Note that this will generate error messages if there are any sub-directories of test/ (because they will match the `*` glob but you have not used `-r`).

BTW, while it's not strictly required, it's best to **always** have a trailing `/` on a directory.  It can prevent disastrous mistakes, especially with old versions of utilities that offer no built-in protection against doing things like accidentally `mv`-ing hundreds of files onto one single file (all but the last file moved is gone!). That trailing / will cause the mv to fail if the target is not a directory.   Most modern versions of tools will detect and prevent mistakes like this unless you go out of your way to override that behaviour and force them not to.

The trailing / also self-documenting, it makes it obvious that you want to copy to or from a directory, not just a single file.

---

(*) there are exceptions, but they're usually specific options to override the common practice (i.e. source before target) and allow you to put the destination directory before all the source file(s).

e.g. the `-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY` options in GNU versions of `cp`, `mv`, `ln`, etc.   This is mostly for convenience to make it easier to use these programs with other programs like `find ... -exec ...` or `xargs` (it's easier to add a list of source filenames to the end of a command than to insert them in the middle).